# WordPress Site - PayPal IPNs failing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

First time using PayPal IPNs. Here is the scenario.

- I have a WordPress test site using [Events Manager Pro](http://eventsmanagerpro.com/) Plugin
- I have the Payment Gateway setup within this Plugin to use PayPal Sandbox
- I have an IPN notification URL
- Intermittently the IPN messages seems to be failing. Below is the log.
- I tried this on two different domains hosted on two different service providers (inmotionhosting.com and justhost.com) and are experiencing intermittent IPN message failures.
- Any idea how I can troubleshoot and fix this? Any help appreciated.

Here is the screenshot of the IPN History:
[image: IPN History]

Comment: If you click on the IPN message ID, what does it say under 'HTTP Status code'?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your verification code is being pulled correctly.

Check all parameters is the message and compare it with the IPN messages that are being completed succesfully

Use the IPN simualator to test your messages